# Deduce from a given fact the circumstances under which $-2$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\xi=e^{\pi i/4}$.

By making use of the representation $\sqrt{-2}=\xi-\xi^{-1}$, how do I show that $-2$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod p$ iff $p\equiv 1 \text{ or } 3 \bmod 8$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix an odd prime $ p $, and note that $ \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb F_{p^2} $. The question of determining whether $ 2 $ is a quadratic residue modulo $ p $ comes down to determining whether $ \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb F_p $. Let $ \sigma : x \to x^p $ be the Frobenius at $ p $, then the fixed field of $ \sigma $ is precisely $ \mathbb F_p $. Therefore, $ 2 $ is a quadratic residue modulo $ p $ if and only if $ \sigma(\sqrt{2}) = \sqrt{2} $. Now, observe the following:

$$ \sigma(\sqrt{2}) = \sigma(\xi + \xi^{-1}) = \xi^p + \xi^{-p} $$

It is easy to check that if $ p $ is $ 1 $ or $ 7 $ modulo $ 8 $, then this last expression is $ = \xi + \xi^{-1} $, so $ \sigma $ fixes $ \sqrt{2} $. Hence, $ 2 $ is a quadratic residue modulo $ p $. On the other hand, if $ p $ is $ 3 $ or $ 5 $ modulo $ 8 $, then we have

$$ \xi^p + \xi^{-p} = \xi^3 + \xi^5 = \xi^4 (\xi + \xi^{-1}) = -\sqrt{2} $$

so that $ \sqrt{2} $ is not fixed. Thus, in these cases, $ 2 $ is not a quadratic residue modulo $ p $.

Now, combining this with the result that $ -1 $ is a quadratic residue modulo $ p $ iff $ p $ is $ 1 $ modulo $ 4 $ gives the result.